# Validation of an order

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, triggers

I have an management application of sales, stock and payment on a warehouse whole saler from a web interface. In particular, when a order is efectuated it must created a line corresponding to each product ordered with the respective quantity. The validation of the stock availability is done on the moment of the order.

Considering the following two ways of validation to on order:

1) Using a trigger "BEFORE...ON INSERT" on the table OrderLine, that does a SELECT on Product veridying if exists enough Stock.

2) Doing a SELECT...FROM OrderLine JOIN Product WHERE quant

My question is on which situation each one of this two alternatives is more likely? And why?

Thanks

Comment: Just my two cents - handle the validation in the business logic layer of your application.

Comment: I believe the problem you are trying to deal with is the gap in time between the validation check and the data insert. You should be able to leverage transactions with the appropriate isolation levels to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the (unwritten) third option.

1. Use a stored procedure ([in PostgreSQL, a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html)) to place the order. Inside the function use (probably) as many [serializable transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) as you need.

Even if you do that work in the application layer, you still need to do all the checking and submitting in a single transaction, probably in a single, serializable transaction.

Depending on your application, serializable transactions might not work for you. Some  online vendors accept an order without guaranteeing they have enough stock to fill it. Later, you might get an email saying something has been backordered.  (Just something to keep in mind.)

[General information about PostgreSQL transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-transactions.html)

Comment: althoug I think your answer is the right onde. If you only could choose between of of the two option I give what is the one that you choose?

Comment: @fegol: Neither of them complete the job you seem to want--making sure that existing stock is used to complete *this* order and not some other order.